# How to create an async function that waits on an event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I block on the event?

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
const util = require('util');

function Task() {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
    this.setMaxListeners(Infinity);

    this.dosomething = () => {
    console.log("do something");
    };

    this.run = (iter) => {
    for(i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
            this.dosomething();
        this.emit('someevent');
    }
    }

}

util.inherits(Task, EventEmitter);

task = new Task();

function do_work() {
    console.log("work 1");
    task.once('someevent', (props) => {
    console.log('event happened');
    });
    console.log("work 2");
}

do_work();
task.run(5);
```

**Acutal Result** 
work 1 
work 2 
do something 
event happened 
do something 
do something 
do something 
do something

**Expected Result** 
work 1 
do something 
event happened 
work 2 
do something 
do something 
do something 
do something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then this can be achieved via a `Promise` that wraps the `task` event handler:

```
async function do_work() {

  console.log("work 1");

  // use a promise to block completion of do_work() function
  // until task event callback has been invoked
  await (new Promise(resolve => {

    task.once('someevent', (props) => {

      console.log('event happened');

      // Now that task callback has been invoked, "resolve" the
      // enclosing promise to allow do_work()'s execution to complete
      resolve();

    });
  }));

  console.log("work 2");
}
```

The idea in the code above is to wrap the task `someevent` handler so that the promise `resolve` can be invoked once the event handler has fired (ie by calling `resolve()`). This allows the call to `do_work()` to resume, to achieve the desired execution behavior.

Also, you will need to do something like this:

```
// Because do_work() is async, and becase you want to ensure that
// do_work() completes before starting task.run(5), you need to enclose
// these in an async function, eg doWorkThenRunTasks()
async function doWorkThenRunTasks() {

  // Call do_work asynchronously
  await do_work()

  // task.run will happen after do_work completed
  task.run(5);
}

doWorkThenRunTasks();
```

The addition of the async `doWorkThenRunTasks()` function allows you to use `await` in relation to `do_work()` to enforce execution order of `task.run(5)` after completion of `do_work()`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!